# Why is AutoResetEvent.waitone returning false in my test?

Tags: c#, mono

Hello so I'm doing a unit test in c# with Mono. I'm testing a async method that uses delegates to return the response of a web service.
So here is my test:

```
[Test]
public void TestCreateUser()
{
    Debug.Log("TestCreateUser");

    Vizzario.Instance.OnCreateUserSuccess += delegate(CreateUserResponse x) 
    {           
        Debug.Log("TestCreateUser: " + x.Response);
        UnityEngine.Assertions.Assert.IsNotNull(x.TokenResponse.AuthToken); 
        UnityEngine.Assertions.Assert.AreEqual(BaseResponse.ResponseEnum.SUCCESS, x.Response);
        // Signal that work is finished.
        bool s = autoResetEvent.Set(); 
        Debug.Log(s);
    };
    // Does the request
    InitData.NewUserData.Email = InitData.GetRandomEmail();
    Vizzario.Instance.CreateUser(InitData.NewUserData);

    // Wait for work method to signal.
    bool a = autoResetEvent.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), true);
    Debug.Log(a);
}
```

So when I run this test the result from WaitOne executes before executing the body of my MyClass.Instance.OnCreateUserSuccess and it prints false.

So it prints something like: 1. false, 2. TestCreateUser: Success
When it should print something like: 1. TestCreateUser: Success, 2. true

Why is the waitone not working, I try increasing autoResetEvent.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), true); to autoResetEvent.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60), true); but I got the same results I know as a fact that the CreateUser method doesn't take more than 1 or 2 seconds so if I try autoResetEvent.WaitOne(); my test hangs and I have to restart the ide.
Any ideas.
Thanks in advance!

As requested I'm adding the method that is called in my vizzario class:

```
   public delegate void CreateUserCallback(CreateUserResponse response);
    public event CreateUserCallback OnCreateUserSuccess;
    public event CreateUserCallback OnCreateUserError;

    public void CreateUser(NewUserData data)
    {
        CreateUserResponse response = new CreateUserResponse();

        this.DefApi.UserPost(data, ApiKey, ToolkitVersion, dryRun)
        .Then(x =>
        {
            response.TokenResponse = x;
            response.Response = BaseResponse.ResponseEnum.SUCCESS;
            DoCreateUserNext(response);
        })
        .Catch(e =>
        {
            response.Response = BaseResponse.ResponseEnum.ERROR;
        });
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return callback in case of an exception inside the sdk.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void DoCreateUserError(Exception e)
    {
      if (OnCreateUserError != null)
      {
        CreateUserResponse response = new CreateUserResponse();
        response.Response = BaseResponse.ResponseEnum.ERROR;
        response.message = e.Message;
        OnCreateUserError(response);
      }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return callback from the sdk to the developer.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="response"></param>
    private void DoCreateUserNext(CreateUserResponse response)
    {
      if (OnCreateUserSuccess != null)
      {
        if (response.Response == BaseResponse.ResponseEnum.SUCCESS)
        {
          OnCreateUserSuccess(response);
        }
      }
      if (OnCreateUserError != null)
      {
        if (response.Response == BaseResponse.ResponseEnum.ERROR)
        {
          OnCreateUserError(response);
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Write an async test method

Comment: could you show your Vizzario class as well? at lease the Instance class would be helpful (are you calling OnCreateUserSuccess from the CreateUser method?).